# Creating LINQ to SQL for counting a parameter

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to translate a sql query into LINQ to SQL.  I keep getting an error "sequence operators not supported for type 'system.string'"  If I take out the distinct count part, it works.  Is it not because I'm using the GROUP BY?

```
SELECT    COUNT(EpaValue) AS [Leak Count], Location, EpaValue AS [Leak Desc.]
FROM         ChartMes.dbo.RecourceActualEPA_Report
WHERE     (EpaName = N'LEAK1') AND (Timestamp) > '20100429030000'
GROUP BY EpaValue, Location
ORDER BY Location, [Leak Count] DESC


Dim temp = (From p In db2.RecourceActualEPA_Reports _
                     Where (p.Timestamp >= str1stShiftStart) And (p.Timestamp < str2ndShiftCutoff) _
                     And (p.EpaName = "Leak1") _
                     Select p.EpaName.Distinct.Count(), p.Location, p.EpaValue)
```

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.EpaName` seems to be a string, not a collection so you can't apply `Count()` there.

Here is the query you're trying to build (according to your SQL query) using LINQ (I'm not familiar with VB, so the query is written in C#):

```
var temp =  
    db2.RecourceActualEPA_Reports
        .Where(p =>
                p.Timestamp >= str1stShiftStart &&
                p.Timestamp < str2ndShiftCutoff &&
                p.EpaName == "Leak1"
        ).GroupBy(p => new { Key1 = p.EpaValue, Key2 = p.Location })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            Count = g.Count(),
            Value = g.Key.Key1,
            Location = g.Key.Key2
        }).OrderBy(i => new { i.Location, i.Count });
```

And please, in the future format and highlight your code using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), not (or not only) using VS/Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is formatted in SQL and in Visual Studio
SQL

---

SELECT COUNT(EpaValue) AS [Leak Count], Location, EpaValue AS [Leak Desc.]
FROM ChartMes.dbo.RecourceActualEPA_Report
WHERE (EpaName = N'LEAK1') AND (Timestamp) > '20100429030000'
GROUP BY EpaValue, Location
ORDER BY Location, [Leak Count] DESC

VB

---

Dim temp = (From p In db2.RecourceActualEPA_Reports _
Where (p.Timestamp >= str1stShiftStart) And (p.Timestamp < str2ndShiftCutoff) _
And (p.EpaName = "Leak1") _
Select p.EpaName.Distinct.Count(), p.Location, p.EpaValue)